# CocoaAsyncTask can't connect real device

Tags: objective-c, ios, tcp, cocoaasyncsocket

I'm using CocoaAsyncTask and trying to connect to the localhost.
When I run it from the simulator, it works (I'm checking it with the provided echo server)
but when I run it on the actual device, nothing happens..
the code is:

```
if(![socket connectToHost:@"localhost" onPort:8080 error:nil]) {
    NSLog(@"Error..");
}
-(void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host: port:(uint16_t)port {
    NSLog(@"Connected");
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What service are you expecting on the iOS device itself that is serving on port 8080?

Comment: The port itself doesn't matter.. I tried using 4444 as well. at the moment just sending string. it works from the simulator. not from the device

Comment: So you are running both, a server and the client on a non jailbroken device, correct?

Comment: No, the server is at the Macbook (or PC, tried both) and the client is an iphone

Comment: Well, in that case "localhost" won't do. You need to provide the IP-address of your MacBook (or PC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are providing the address as being "localhost" whilst you attempt to connect to a server that is not locally installed (local = on the exact same host and interface). 
See the [wikipedia entry on "localhost"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).

It works from the simulator as that one uses your Mac's networking interface, hence "localhost" refers to the machine you run the server from as well as the client.

You will need to provide the local IP address of your hosting machine (e.g. your Mac). Usually that is something like 192.168.1.100 or 192.168.0.100 - but to be more precise on that stuff;

> 192.168.xxx.xxx = class C non-routable addresses
>
> 10.xxx.xxx.xxx = class A non-routable addresses

Whereas ***xxx*** stands for any value between 0 and 255.

To find out about your local IP-address, use the *System Preferences* -> *Network Panel*. Check the value below *Status* for ***"...the IP address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"***

[image]

Comment: I tried. didn't work either.. I checked my ip from www.whatismyip.com
to verify

Comment: You tried a non-local address but that is not what your Mac is reachable on if you are behind a router with a firewall. Either open that port on your firewall or use a local address.

Comment: i'll give it a shot tommorow.
If I want to use the non local address (to test from outside the local network) i need to test with the address obtained from www.whatismyip.com (or ipconfig..) and open the port in the router? that's it?

Comment: First try it using local routing (local IP address). Then, if that works as intended, go ahead and make sure the selected port is reachable remotely. For more on that issue, see the documentation of your router/firewall.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it tommorow!
Thanks a lot for you help

Comment: Note, your iOS device has to be connected to the very same network for attempting a local routing approach. That is, it has to be connected via WiFi to the same router/network your server (mac/pc) is connected to.